# Compare 2 columns in Excel and copy data from 3rd column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to compare 2 columns that don't have the same size (one has 205 entries, the other 440) and if the data from column B matches the data in column A, the data from column C must be copied in column D at the same level of the entry that matched in column A. How can I do this?

Please let me know if you need more info. I don't know how to copy part of the sheet in order for you to get an exact idea of what I'm talking about.

Stefan

Comment: Which column has 205 and which has 440?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [Lookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342670) problem

Assuming Column A is the column with 205 entries and your data has headers:

in Cell D2 use a vlookup formula:

```
= VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$C$440, 2, FALSE)
```

Copy down this formula to D205

*et voila*

Comment: It partially worked. I get some answers but most of them are #N/A.

In column A I have IDs of employees (205 of them), in column B I have 440 IDs (205 that are in column A + extra) and in column C I have the names of the 205 from column A. I want to associate their names with the IDs from column B in column D.

Comment: Oops. Need to Absolute Reference the array.  Ie, change the middle argument to the vlookup function in cell D2 to:  $B$2:$C$440 Then copy/down again.  Changed in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to find out the duplicate records from Column A to Column B.
Pivot table is a better option for find a duplicate records Microsoft Excel.
Select the whole data(Column A and Column B) select Insert tab -> Pivot Table.
Select the column A and Column B in Row format, all the duplicate entries are filtered by itself.